# Why are browsers autofilling my email field with password?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, forms

So I have a multi step register form, in the first step I want the user to give me email, password and confirm password. Pretty standard stuff. So as the first step I render:

```
type UserData = {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  confirmPassword: string;
};

type UserFormProps = UserData & {
  updateFields: (fields: Partial<UserData>) => void;
};

const UserForm = ({
  email,
  password,
  confirmPassword,
  updateFields,
}: UserFormProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
      <input
        autoFocus
        required
        type="email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => updateFields({ email: e.target.value })}
        id="email"
        name="email"
      />
      <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
      <input
        required
        type="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(e) => updateFields({ password: e.target.value })}
        name="password"
        id="password"
      />
      <label htmlFor="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
      <input
        required
        type="password"
        value={confirmPassword}
        onChange={(e) => updateFields({ confirmPassword: e.target.value })}
        name="confirm-password"
        id="confirm-password"
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default UserForm;
```

Why are browsers auto-filling my email and confirm-password fields with a password suggestion? I explicitly gave type password to the second and third input fields. What is even weirder - confirm-password input field is displaying typed characters normally (not like type password would suggest - stars or dots). Any ideas what could be causing this issue?
Parent component is not really important, it handles step changes, wraps steps in one form component etc.

Comment: Autofill is the browser functionality. You can disable it via browser settings or explicitly in the form fields. Please refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tags

Comment: Tried disabling browser extensions? Private browsing / incognito mode? A different browser? This doesn't seem reproducible

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear enough. The problem is not the fact that the browser gives autofill suggestions but the fact that it puts password in my email input field. The second issue is why is my confirm password field (of type password) showing visible characters while typing

Answer (score -1):

It's because browser store that information and you can not change this functionality. For that you need to clear it from browser. then this issue will fix.

For test you code Please open it as incognito mode so their you didn't receive any  auto sugegstion.

For remove Auto Fill please [https://tech.hindustantimes.com/tech/news/how-to-disable-google-chrome-autofill-option-71655818171378.html#:~:text=You%20can%20also%20go%20to,methods%2C%20%26%20Addresses%20and%20more](https://tech.hindustantimes.com/tech/news/how-to-disable-google-chrome-autofill-option-71655818171378.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20go%20to,methods%2C%20%26%20Addresses%20and%20more).